# set a pdf file as NSButton's image

Tags: cocoa, pdf, nsimage, nsbutton

i want to set a pdf file as a NSButton's image, and when i clicked the button,the button's color changed, just like the xcode's navigator editor. can some one tell me how to do this? thanks in advance!
![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Is this a pdf you dynamically download?

Comment: no ,it's a local file

Comment: here is a pic:  http://ask.csdn.net/questions/171276#answer_48157

Answer (score 0):

Arguably you're better off converting the pdf to a png so you can handle it more easily.

But, you can create an image from the pdf and use that with the button:

```
NSPDFImageRep *pdfRep = [NSPDFImageRep imageRepWithData:pdfData]; 

NSImage *pdfImg = [[NSImage alloc] init]; 
[pdfImg addRepresentation:pdfRep];
```

Comment: yes, thanks!  but i want to know how to change parts of the button's color, just like the editor navigator button in xcode, when clicked the button,  a part of the button become blue color.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the button you mean. That won't be done using a pdf, it will be a template image with a tint colour

Comment: sorry,my reputation is too low to upload a pic.

Comment: You can add a link. Take a look at something like https://gist.github.com/knassar/ee29c3a2d969a6b00770